# Java ThreadPoolExecutor with Serializable and Runnable queue elements (Compile error: no suitable constructor found for...)

Tags: java, runnable, serializable, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to create a replicated BlockingQueue implementation to use in a cluster environment as a distributed task cache.

Since it has to be distributed i need all elements of the queue to be Serializable. This is how i define the class;

```
public class ReplicatedBlockingQueue<E extends Serializable> implements BlockingQueue<E>
```

Then i create a blocking queue implementation with Runnable "Job" class, which is both Serializable and Runnable

```
public class Job implements Runnable,Serializable
```

By the time i use this queue to create a ThreadPoolExecutor, Java complains that ReplicatedBlockingQueue is not a defined constructor

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,4, new ReplicatedBlockingQueue<Job>());
```

If Runnable interface was extending Serializable i would be able to create replicated queue as follows:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,4, new ReplicatedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

But unfortunately Runnable is not Serializable

How can i use my ReplicatedBlockingQueue implementation with ThreadPoolExecutor ?

EDIT: Using Java6

EDIT: Posted the example on the following link. You can compile online by clicking edit button. http://ideone.com/JFFDNa

Comment: Why can't you use the last option?  Why does it have to be Serializable here?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Because ReplicatedQueue is declared as E extends Serializable and Runnable is not Serializable

Comment: How about `new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,4, new ReplicatedBlockingQueue());` ?

Comment: That worked :) There appears unchecked warning but that is ok. Can you post that as an answer ? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to tell the compiler you know the type will be fine.  In this situation it is easier to use an unchecked type.

```
// produces a warning but works.
new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,4, new ReplicatedBlockingQueue());
```

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the method to turn the warning off.

Comment: Thanks, all elements will be Runnable Job objects at runtime. So i won't bother with warning and suppress them. Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` expects a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`, which `ReplicatedBlockingQueue` isn't, since it is a `BlockingQueue<E extends Serializable>`.

You need to declare `ReplicatedBlockingQueue<E extends Serializable & Runnable>` to make `E` extend `Runnable` and be usable as a return type for the methods inherited from BlockingQueue, and you must parametrize `BlockingQueue` with `Runnable`, as it is the explicitly expected type for `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
public class ReplicatedBlockingQueue<E extends Serializable & Runnable> 
            implements BlockingQueue<Runnable> {
    @Override
        public E remove() {
        }
```

...

Comment: Wow, i did not know i could & operator at that place. Still it doesn't work. I actually tried creating an interface SerializableRunnable which extends both Serializable and Runnable and defined ReplicatedBlockingQueue<E extends SerializableRunnable> and it did not work like that neither.

Comment: Btw, i am using Java6 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: java6 does not make a difference here. I have tested using the code I posted, and I though that was the result you were searching for. Can you explain what does not work/is not satisfactory in that solution so I can try to narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPoolExecutor requires a non generic BlockingQueue so try this:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor( 4, 4, keepAlive, timeUnit, new ReplicatedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() );
```

Comment: I did try it, but since ReplicatedBlockingQueue is declared as E extends Serializable new ReplicatedBlockingQueue<Runnable> can't be initiated, because Runnable interface is not Serializable.

Comment: So make it E extends Runnable.

Comment: Yea, but Replicated queue actually extends ReplicatedQueue which requires Serializable elements. It has to be Serializable, since elemements get replicated over network

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor executes Runnables consider the #execute method. Giving it a ReplicatedQueue that takes a serializable will not give you any value. Just declare it with Runnables and ensure that you are only giving it runnables that are serializable. Or, wrap it as a private instance of custom executor that has an #execute method that takes SerializableRunnables.

Comment: Well i was going to wrap it another class and use it as a delegator. But new ReplicatedBlockingQueue() with unchecked conversion seems better since i might be using ReplicatedBlockingQueue for other purposes then passing it to a ThreadPoolExecutor. Will only put Runnable elements in it. So problem solved.

Comment: Yeah, even so it won't enforce the RepliacatedBlockingQueue types because ThreadPoolExecutor only checks Runnable at runtime and the only way to get your ReplicatedBlockingQueue in there is if you cast it to Runnable which will defeat your purpose.